# driver.get buffer when access this mp4 url

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

dependencies version :

- chromedriver version is 2.41
- selenium 3.14

my code :

```
print("Access Video")
driver.get("http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4")
print("finish")
```

1. the video has been fully loaded but driver.get still buffer
2. i try adding timeout, but it's not solution

Comment: Can you access the website without the mp4? If so you can just find the XPATH and download it!

Comment: my purpose is not to download the video, but to get the public video url which is redirected from facebook protected url, the point is how to not get buffer like that

Comment: hi folks, the problem was on the chromedriver, [link to chromedriver issue tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2621&q=&sort=-pri&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary)

Comment: You should post this as an answer... Of course you should explain more...

Comment: Just for your information you can expect your one question... Welcome to StakOverflow pal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the actual problem is on the chromedriver it self not in selenium, the fact **selenium is waiting return from chromedriver**, and by the way geckodriver doesn't have issue with this [19-10-2018 5:39 GMT +7].

[[2621] buffer until timeout when access mp4 url](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2621&q=&sort=-pri&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary) (link to chromedriver issue tracker)